# Extract text from first, second and third brackets in R

Tags: r, regex, text, extract

I have the following dataframe in R:

```
text <- c("[AAA]xxxx", "[AAA] yyyrrr", "[AAA][bbb] bla", "[AAA][bbb] cccvvv", 
      "[AAA][bbb] bla", "[AAA][bbb][CcC] bla", "[AAA][bbb][CcC] xbbpr") 
value <- rnorm(7)
df <- data.frame(text, value)
```

I would like to create three new variables in my dataframe for the text contained in the first, second and third bracket pairs, respectively.

The desired output would look like this:

```
                  text       value Bracket1 Bracket2 Bracket3
1             [AAA]xxxx -0.01819034      AAA       NA       NA
2          [AAA] yyyrrr -0.24808460      AAA       NA       NA
3        [AAA][bbb] bla -0.36293689      AAA      bbb       NA
4     [AAA][bbb] cccvvv  1.27757055      AAA      bbb       NA
5        [AAA][bbb] bla -0.46889715      AAA      bbb       NA
6   [AAA][bbb][CcC] bla  0.07105410      AAA      bbb      CcC
7 [AAA][bbb][CcC] xbbpr -0.26603845      AAA      bbb      CcC
```

I have not been able to extract the text from the first brackets, much less second or third.

For instance, I have tried:

```
    df$Bracket1 <- gsub('.*\\[(.*)\\].*', '\\1', text)
```

and

```
    df$Bracket1 <- sub('.*\\[(.*)\\].*', '\\1', text)
```

But these both yield:

```
                   text       value    Bracket1
1             [AAA]xxxx -0.01819034         AAA
2          [AAA] yyyrrr -0.24808460         AAA
3        [AAA][bbb] bla -0.36293689         bbb
4     [AAA][bbb] cccvvv  1.27757055         bbb
5        [AAA][bbb] bla -0.46889715         bbb
6   [AAA][bbb][CcC] bla  0.07105410         CcC
7 [AAA][bbb][CcC] xbbpr -0.26603845         CcC
```

I am brand new to regex and relatively new to R, thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Here is a [weird solution based on `gsub`](http://ideone.com/9012mP).

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much for your help. I have no idea what it means yet, so now I will dig into your syntax and piece it all together. Would you submit as an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach using `gregexpr` and `regmatches`:

```
mtchs <- regmatches(df$text, gregexpr("\\[\\w+\\]", df$text))
```

Then just reorganize the output to the desired structure:

```
library(plyr) # for rbind.fill
df[,3:5] <- do.call(rbind.fill,
            lapply(mtchs, function(xx) {x <- data.frame(matrix(xx, nrow=1))
                                        names(x) <- paste0("Bracket", 1:length(xx))
                                        x}))
# or using dplyr's bind_row:
library(dplyr)
df[,3:5] <- bind_rows(lapply(mtchs, function(xx) {x <- data.frame(matrix(xx, nrow=1))
                    names(x) <- paste0("Bracket", 1:length(xx))
                    x}))
# or using data.table's rbindlist:
library(data.table)
df[,3:5] <-  rbindlist(lapply(mtchs, function(xx) {x <- data.frame(matrix(xx, nrow=1))
                    names(x) <- paste0("Bracket", 1:length(xx))
                    x}), fill=TRUE)
```

You can change the regular expression in `regmatches` to get rid of the brackets if you want:

```
mtchs <- regmatches(df$text, gregexpr("(?<=\\[)\\w+(?=\\])", df$text, perl=TRUE))
```

Comment: This is great, plus you've shown me some new functions, thank you for your help!

Comment: @czimm Also, have a look at Arun's answer, which is more elegant than mine!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `gsub` based solution: if we have a match, group 1 text is kept, and if no match with brackets is found the whole string is matched and replaced with empty  group 1.

```
df$Bracket1 <- gsub('(?:.*?\\[([^][]*)\\].*|.*)', '\\1', text, perl=T)
df$Bracket2 <- gsub('(?:.*?\\[[^][]*\\].*?\\[([^][]*)\\].*|.*)', '\\1', text, perl=T)
df$Bracket3 <- gsub('(?:.*?\\[[^][]*\\].*?\\[[^][]*\\].*?\\[([^][]*)\\].*|.*)', '\\1', text, perl=T)
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/9012mP).

Answer (score 1):

Using `transpose()` from `data.table` package:

```
require(data.table) # v1.9.6+
dt = data.table(text, value) # text is character
vals = regmatches(dt$text, gregexpr("(?<=\\[)[[:alpha:]]+(?=])", dt$text, perl=TRUE))

dt[, paste0("Bracket", 1:3) := transpose(vals)]
#                     text      value Bracket1 Bracket2 Bracket3
# 1:             [AAA]xxxx -0.9285790      AAA       NA       NA
# 2:          [AAA] yyyrrr  0.7928830      AAA       NA       NA
# 3:        [AAA][bbb] bla  0.1177066      AAA      bbb       NA
# 4:     [AAA][bbb] cccvvv  1.1818542      AAA      bbb       NA
# 5:        [AAA][bbb] bla -0.4476371      AAA      bbb       NA
# 6:   [AAA][bbb][CcC] bla  2.2992593      AAA      bbb      CcC
# 7: [AAA][bbb][CcC] xbbpr  2.1161453      AAA      bob      CcC
```

Comment: Nice, thanks Arun, transpose() is also a new one for me.